# Wordpress site “Service unavailable” on Desktop but working on mobile

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-503

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but kindly bear with me with the following issue:

I was working on a WordPress website that is hosted on GoDaddy.

Everything was working fine till it went on a "Service unavailable" mode this morning. Upon checking on mobile, it works fine. However, it doesn't work on desktop on all browsers I tested it on (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera).

What could be the issue? I have yet to get the cpanel credentials from my client?

TIA.

Comment: Probably a Fatal error while executing script. Check logs for the error

Comment: @LogicBlower I'm still waiting for cpanel credentials. Its just weird it works on mobile browsers but not on desktop browsers.

Comment: can you share the  web url, may be we can have a look. And i guess in wordpress there are scripts that executes as per platform (like a slider to show only in desktop mode is not responding)

Comment: I finally solved my problem. Its just a matter of clearing my dns cache. Thank you @LogicBlower

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue. Its a matter of clearing my DNS cache (via this command in command prompt: ipconfig /flushdns )

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+To+Clear+Your+DNS+Cache